# Slide UIView Transitions

Tags: xcode, uiview, xcode4, transition, slide

I want to switch views in a viewcontroller with a transition slide. I found the following code online.

```
//  get  the  view  that's  currently  showing 
UIView *currentView = self.view; 
//  get  the  the  underlying  UIWindow,  or  the  view  containing  the  current  view  view 
UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview]; 

//  remove  the  current  view  and  replace  with  myView1 
[currentView removeFromSuperview]; 
[theWindow  addSubview:PlayingView]; 
PlayingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
//  set  up  an  animation  for  the  transition  between  the  views 
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation]; 
[animation setDuration:1]; 
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush]; 
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft]; 
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```

This code words great but there is a VERY annoying white strip on the bottom!  I found the code:

```
  PlayingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
```

which doesn't seem to work.

So, the link to the place I found http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/13427-uiview-slide-transition.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code is not the problem.

Comment: @anon what do you think it is then?

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be 480 high, not 460, but you should instead use `PlayingView.frame = theWindow.bounds` instead of manually creating the CGRect.  It'll also work in a universal app or for landscape.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not displaying the status bar then the height of the screen is 480 (the status bar is 20 pixels).  So try changing it to CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480).